# Clamping magnitude of 2 vectors

Tags: geometry

I am trying to implement a robotic movement pipeline where I can control the robots velocity in $x$ and $y$ directions. I get $x$ velocity and $y$ velocity using that I can move the robot in a particular direction. 
I am looking for a way to clamp the total velocity of the robot.

For example, if $x_{\text{vel}}=10$ and $y_{\text{vel}}=10$ then the total velocity of the robot will be $$\left((10)^2+(10)^2\right)^{1/2}=14.4$$

I want to clamp the max velocity of the robot in any direction is this possible if so then how?

Comment: Please typeset your questions using MathJax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?rq=1

Comment: What do you mean by clamping?

Comment: Just restrict $x_{\text{vel}}^2+y_{\text{vel=10}}^2$ to the square of your desired maximum or less

Comment: @Tavish i want to limit the total magnitude of the incoming $x_{\text{vel}}$ and $y_{\text{vel}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: To get the velocity $v_\phi$ in the direction determined by the angle $\phi$ which the velocity makes with the axis $x$, just use:
$$
v_x=v_\phi\cos\phi;\\
v_y=v_\phi\sin\phi.
$$

Comment: Seems promising I'll try this, so i should calculate the angle and magnitude then I can clamp the magnitude and revert back to x and y ?